# Format a string in C

Tags: c

Normally you can print a string in C like this..

```
printf("No record with name %s found\n", inputString);
```

But I wanted to make a string out of it, how I can do it? I am looking for something like this..

```
char *str = ("No record with name %s found\n", inputString);
```

I hope it is clear what I am looking for...

Comment: Do yourself a favor & go buy "The C Programming Language" by  Kernigham & Ritchie.

Comment: http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/cclass.html

Answer (score 30, accepted):

One option would be to use [`sprintf`](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/c/io/sprintf), which works just like `printf` but takes as its first parameter a pointer to the buffer into which it should place the resulting string.

It is preferable to use [`snprintf`](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/c/io/snprintf), which takes an additional parameter containing the length of the buffer to prevent buffer overruns.  For example:

```
char buffer[1024];
snprintf(buffer, 1024, "No record with name %s found\n", inputString);
```

Answer (score 10):

You're looking for the `sprintf` family of functions.  Their general format is:

```
char output[80];
sprintf(output, "No record with name %s found\n", inputString);
```

However, `sprintf` by itself is *extremely* dangerous.  It is prone to something called buffer overruns.  What this means it that sprintf has no idea how big the `output` string you provide it is, so it will willingly write more data to it than is available.  For example, this will compile cleanly, but will overwrite valid memory—and there is no way to let `sprintf` know that it's doing anything wrong:

```
char output[10];
sprintf(output, "%s", "This string is too long");
```

The solution is to use a function as `snprintf`, which takes a length parameter:

```
char output[10];
snprintf(output, sizeof output, "%s", "This string is too long, but will be truncated");
```

or, if you're on a Windows system, to use the `_sntprintf` variants and friends, which protect against overflowing of either the input or output strings.

Comment: As it's a homework question, I'd just to point out that `sizeof output` only gives the number of *elements* in a `char` array - the usual practice is to use: `sizeof array / sizeof array[0]`, which works without being dependent upon the size of various types. Plus, it works for `char` arrays too. :)

Comment: Good point.  Even that, though, can fail in some really common cases, such as passing `array` to a function--at which point, `sizeof array` is 4 or 8 on any modern system, regardless of the number and size of the elements therein.  The real solution is to use `std::vector` or something similar and avoid the whole mess entirely.

Answer (score 7):

Since this is homework (thanks for tagging it as such) I'll suggest you to look closely at the `...printf()` family of functions.

I'm sure you'll find the solution :)

Comment: Well, it looks like others alredy deprived you of the pleasure of discovery :)

Comment: +1 anyway for giving the right kind of answer to a homework question.

Answer (score 3):

Look into sprintf (see below).

```
int n = sprintf(str, "No record with name %s found\n", inputString);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
sprintf(str, "No record with name %s found\n", inputString);
```